# Expected value when rolling dice

Tags: probability, expectation

If I roll two fair dice and let $Y$ be the number obtained by multipling the scores, the expected value of $Y$ is $E[Y]=\dfrac{49}{4}$. Let $X$ be the score obtained by rolling a single fair die. Then $E[X]=\dfrac{7}{2}$. Is it a coincidence that $E[Y]=(E[X])^2$?

Comment: no, its not a coincidence. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/544654/173262).

Comment: No coincidence: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Expectation_of_product_of_random_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem $1$.** If $A$ and $B$ are independent discrete random variables, then $$E[A]\times E[B]=E[AB].$$

*Proof.*

$$\begin{aligned}E[AB]&=\sum_{a,b}abP(A=a \cap B=b)\\
&=\sum_{a,b}abP(A=a)P(B=b) \quad\quad\quad \text{ (since $A$ and $B$ are independent)}\\
&=\left(\sum_a aP(A=a)\right)\left(\sum_b bP(B=b)\right)\\
&=E[A]E[B]
\end{aligned}$$

> **Theorem $2$.** If $A$ and $B$ are independent continuous random variables, then 
>   $$E[A]\times E[B]=E[AB].$$

*Proof.*

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606205/why-is-it-that-exy-exey-if-x-and-y-are-uncorrelated-random-variabl).